# TweetSharp - Get User Email ID after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

I am using TweetSharp for user login in my asp.net mvc web app. All works fine but after login I need to save the user data in my DB as well. I cant find email from  TwitterUser object after loging. How can i get user's email once the user is authenticated?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The Twitter API doesn't return email addresses for users.

Take a look at the [users/show documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) to see all the information you can retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is whitelisted, you can now retrieve the email as part of `verify_credentials` https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials